# How to append all files in directory using column from CSV?

Tags: python, loops, csv, directory

I have a directory with 10,000 images.  They are labeled 1.png, 2.png, etc.  I have a CSV file with 10,000 labels like frog, truck, etc.  How do I loop through all files to add the label from the CSV?  1.png becomes 'frog.1.png' assuming frog is label 1 in csv.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import os, sys, fileinput
import pandas as pd
#read csv labels
labels = pd.read_csv('trainLabels.csv',sep=',',header=0,usecols=[1])

#sort files in directory numerically
fnames = sorted([fname for fname in os.listdir(data_dir) 
if fname.endswith('.png')], key=lambda f: int(f.rsplit(os.path.extsep, 1)
[0].rsplit(None,1)[-1]))

#Now that order of labels and files match, rename all files using common counter, i
i = 0
for fname in os.listdir(data_dir):
     os.rename(fnames[i],labels[i]+'.'+fnames[i])
     i = i+1
```

os.rename doesn't work with series and I'm having trouble finding a convention that will accommodate the different data types.

Comment: *"`os.rename` doesn't work with series"*. Not sure what that means.

Comment: Sorry, the error type I get is: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Which value is `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some preparations for the demo:

```
$ for f in `echo "1 2 3 4 10"`; do touch "${f}.png"; done
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e" > names.csv
$ ls
1.png      2.png      3.png      4.png      10.png      names.csv
```

I have `1,2,3,4,10` (instead of `5`) to demonstrate sorting and not create 10 files. It will work exactly same with any number of files.

In Python, running in the same dir:

```
>>> import os
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv', 'r') as file:
...     reader = csv.reader(file)  
...     labels = reader.next()  # reader is a regular iterator, you can also iterate row by row.
>>> labels
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> fnames = [fname for fname in os.listdir('.') if fname.endswith('.png')]
['1.png', '10.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png']  # Because string '10.png' comes earlier than '2.png'
>>> fnames = sorted(fnames, key = lambda f: int(os.path.splitext(f)[0]))  # If fnames contain full paths you will need to modify this
>>> fnames
['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '10.png']  # Now we have correct numerical order
>>> len(labels) == len(fnames)  # For consistency should check this. Depends on your requirements.
True
>>> for label, fname in zip(labels, fnames):
...     os.rename(fname, label + '_' + fname)
```

Result:

```
$ ls
a_1.png    b_2.png    c_3.png    d_4.png    e_10.png   names.csv
```

Notes:

- if you are using different csv reader simply make sure that your `labels` variable contains the names you want, not some object or iterator. I used csv reader from [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).
- if you have more complicated filename structure (not `<number>.png`) you'll make your life harder and will need more code for sorting. If you want to make it easier simply fill all numbers with leading zeroes, e.g. for `10000` files filenames would be `00001.png`, `00002.png` and so on. OS should sort them for you automagically.

Answer (score 1):

from the looks of it your labels variable isn't subscriptable, that means you can't call one of it's elements the way you are.

from the pandas docs:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

pd.read_csv returns a DataFrame or TextParser not a list of lines as i think you're expecting

you don't "need" pandas to read that csv:

```
labels = open('trainLabels.csv','r').read().split('\n')

[labels[i]=labels[i].split(',')[0] for i in range(len(labels))] 
#increment 0 above to whatever the column index you want is, this will return the first column

print(labels) #just to check it looks the way you want it to
```

sure it's an extra line, and not as readable, but you're getting the datastructure you want